# Breadcrumbs in DocPad

Tags: breadcrumbs, docpad

I'm dealing with a project which has a flat hierarchy when it comes to the file and folder structure, that means everything is directly subordinated to the URL. E.g. `myproject.com/page1`

This seems to make it a bit more tricky to integrate a breadcrumb overview of where you are on the page, as the actual hierarchy of contents is not flat. Therefore most of the beginner friendly javascript breadcrumb solutions, which all more or less seem to get the hierarchy out of the file structure tree, won't do the job here.

**I was thinking to use the meta information of the documents to assign/display the hierarchy.** Unfortunately my coffescript skills are way too low to even properly think about how to integrate breadcrumbs at this level.

My idea (which might not be the most clever one?!) was to have values like "tier1", "tier2" and "tier3" in the meta section, which then are converted into a breadcrumb link structure with some **coffeescript magic**.

**Does anyone have any hints how to get this started?** I hope to help others as well by getting this discussion started - maybe we come up with an even niftier solution than my approach?

Comment: Have you figured anything out yet? I'm also interested. :)

Comment: Yeah, but only a very manual approach, but fine enough for my needs. See my comment under balptons suggestion. Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

The DocPad and Bevry Website accomplishes something like this for it's documentation rendering and the corresponding hierarchy. However, the code for this is quite specialised.

A breadcrumbs plugin that makes this super easy would be awesome. The way one could go about is to have a `parent: blah` meta data attribute, with the plugin auto-setting it when it doesn't exist already. It could be set to a relativePath of a document and use `fuzzyFindOne` to find it - https://github.com/bevry/docpad/blob/51bb734dfd064a05d9047ca1f8687aa0a39f5450/src/lib/collections/files.coffee#L22-L42 - however it could also just be set to a string value I guess if the parent document doesn't exist. For parent documents that don't exist, the importers api could be used to inject a document for that anyway.

The question is, do you want your breadcrumbs to be documents/files based? Or category based like the docpad+bevry websites?

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. I now went for a quite manual solution which I was able to work out on my own. To answer your question I think I needed category based breadcrumbs. What I now did is adding the parent category in a field in the meta section, as well as the parent category URL (did not come up with a way to make it automatically, but it's only a few pages anyways). And I simply put it together with some coffeescript in the layout documents. Babysteps, but I'm proud I could solve it :)